# Salesforce REST upsert for externalId cause DUPLICATE_VALUE error

Tags: rest, upsert, externalid, patch, unique-field

I send next upsert request to Salesforce:

```
PATCH /services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Task/uuid__c/a22ac4d6-e2c0-4e53-898d-ea1d0c807775 HTTP/1.1
Host: **********.my.salesforce.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer *******

{
  "Description": "Called C to discuss the reinstall.",
  "CallType": "Outbound",
  "OwnerId": "************",
  "Status": "Completed",
  "Subject": "Call",
  "isTransfer__c": false,
  "WhatId": "************",
  "CallDurationInSeconds": 597,
  "AudioFile__c": "outgoing/2017-10-31/03-10-59_ID-***********.mp3",
  "CallStarted__c": "2017-10-31T07:10:51Z",
  "CallHangup__c": "2017-10-31T07:20:56Z",
  "AsteriskId__c": "7794786",
  "ReasonText__c": "Success call"
}
```

`uuid__c` field is `Unique`, `Case Insensitive` and `external id` marked.

I receive next response from Salesforce:

```
[
    {
        "message": "duplicate value found: uuid__c duplicates value on record with id: *******************",
        "errorCode": "DUPLICATE_VALUE",
        "fields": []
    }
]
```

How it can be if UPSERT request must update object when duplicate found?

I have used this documentation for developing: [Insert or Update (Upsert) a Record Using an External ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm)

Comment: Quick question, does the `uuid__c` of the record mentioned on the error match the `uuid__c` of your request?

Comment: Yes, object has same uuid__c value. (So first upsert completed successfully, it cannot just made update of it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a month of discussions with **Indian** support of all tiers, we've got next:

Salesforce can't proceed too fast UPSERT queries.  If you send two requests with delay about a second or less you'll get next:

1. Your request `1` come to Salesforce and start to save into their DB.
2. Your request `2` come while first request still in work.
3. Salesforce return `DUPLICATE_VALUE` on second request because it think there is no such data in DB yet, and will try to save it also via UPSERT.
4. You've got error above.

**OFFICIAL SOLUTION:** Send your requests with delay at least 2 second each. At least first save completed.

Also from my request, they created an article with description: [Salesforce Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate-value-found-uuid-c-duplicates-value-on-record-with-id-00T0Y00000NChZC-with-PATCH-call-through-REST&language=en_US&type=1)

P.S. They will not change anything, about this behaviour. We spent a **month**, trying to resolve this issue and find the reason with PREMIUM Salesforce support, but results you can see in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation you are referring to says:

> Error responses If the external ID value isn't unique, an HTTP status
>   code 300 is returned, plus a list of the records that matched the
>   query.

Which means: if you have created (somehow when `uuid__c` wasn't unique) two records with the same value of `uuid__c`, then you made `uuid__c` field unique and you are trying to update one of the two records with the same value of `uuid__c` then this will always cause an error.

To resolve this conflict you need change value of `uuid__c` on one record to some unique value.

Comment: Hi and thank you for answer, but it is wrong.
1) I receive code 400
2) uuid__c has already unique index in Salesforce. Also it can't be made unique if there are any duplicates values, so I removed all duplicates and made it unique index before start to use it as ExternalID. (To make it ExternalID there must be no duplicates)

So uuid__c currently - unique + externalid

Comment: @KorbenDallas, your request 1 and request 2 that come to salesforce within less than 1 second , Do they have same value in uuid__c or different values ?

Comment: @apn I have same uuid__c as I'm creating and then updating a call entity.